# Поиск общего префикса в массиве строк JAVA

Tags: java

Начинаю изучать Java. Столкнулся с задачей:
написать функцию для поиска самого длинного префикса среди массива строк.
Пример:

```
Input: ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"
```

Большая просьба, подскажите, какие библиотеки нужно изучить, чтобы понять, как решить данную задачу.

Comment: Эту проблему можно решить без изучения библиотек. Стандартных средств достаточно.

Comment: да двумя циклами(один вложен в другой) можно обойтись. Сначала берите первый символ первой строки. Сравнивайте с первыми символами других строк. Если у всех он тот же, то проворачивайте это дело до того момента, пока хоть один символ на n-ой позиции будет другим.

Comment: Достаточно знать, что такое char и ф-ю charAt класса String

Answer (score 1):

```
public String longestCommonPrefix(String[] strs) {
    if (strs.length == 0)
        return "";
    String prefix = strs[0];
    for (var str : strs)
        // Возвращает целочисленное значение, указывающее начальную 
        // позицию строки в объекте String. 
        // Если строка не найдена, возвращается -1.
        while (str.indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
            // Начальная позиция подстроки не равна 0, 
            // затем подстрока сокращается, а затем сравнивается.
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1); 
            if (prefix.isEmpty())
                return "";
        }
    return prefix;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]